# (Discord.py) (Python) NoneType object error when trying to add roles

Tags: python, nonetype, discord.py

I am trying to have a bot for my Discord be able to add roles. It is able to create roles, but it fails when I try and have it give the role to somebody. Here is my code:

```
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Type in the name of the role you would like to have. This cannot be a role that already exists.')

    roleMessage = await client.wait_for_message(author = message.author)
    roleName = str(roleMessage.content)

    await client.create_role(client.get_server('insertserveridhere'), name = roleName, colour = discord.Colour.orange(), hoist = True, mentionable = True)
    userRole = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name = roleName)
    await client.add_roles(message.author, userRole)
```

I have tried looking at other samples of code that give people roles, and they all seem pretty similar. I don't know what the problem is. Whenever I run it, it says:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

It says that on the line where it adds the role.

EDIT: The `userRole` appears to be the problem on the `add_roles` line, but I don't know why.

EDIT 2: For some reason changing the server id to a different one and then changing it back worked.

EDIT 3: For some reason when I did it on the same server a second time it broke again. I don't understand this at all.

EDIT 4: I got it to work right by making the bot say something in between creating and adding the role. My theory is that it didn't have time to register that the role existed when it tried to add it.

Comment: Looks like you've already answered your own question. It's a timing issue due to the sharded nature of discord.

Comment: It may help to capture the role you create as you create it instead of after you create it. `create_role` returns the role that was created, so you should be able to do `userRole = await client.create_role(...)`